# Multiple account creation in one transaction

Tags: pda, account, instructions, fees

When we create a Solana PDA we construct the instruction, sign it and then send the transaction to Solana cluster. So I would like to know the transaction fees is charged based on nr. of instructions/signatures or something else?
How many maximum number of signature I can create in one transaction to Solana cluster ?

Answer (score 2):

> So I would like to know the transaction fees is charged based on nr. of instructions/signatures or something else?

It's based on the following:

- number of signatures
- eBPF instructions and system calls that get executed inside the transaction (examples of system calls include cross-program invocations, allocating heap memory, and logging)
- any rents that are pre-paid to create accounts

You can read more into the code [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/program-runtime/src/compute_budget.rs).

> How many maximum number of signature I can create in one transaction to Solana cluster ?

The number of required signatures is encoded in an 8-bit value, meaning that there cannot be more than 256 signatures ([src](https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/transactions#message-header-format)).

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question, since if you create an account on a PDA, there's no signature for that account in the transaction! This means that you can create a lot of PDA accounts in one transaction, limited more by the size of the maximum size of the transaction, currently set to 1232 bytes.

So if you assume a payer of 32 bytes, one signature of 64 bytes, and then 32 bytes for each PDA you want to create, you can probably do ~35 accounts: `(1232 - 64 - 32) / 32 = 35.5`

If you use address lookup tables, you could probably get to the current maximum number of accounts allowed in a transaction, which is set to 64 accounts.

Since there's only one signature, the cost of the transaction would still be the minimum cost of 5000 lamports.